# Getting started with Ruby Gem Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Recently I started using a gem called blackbook.  The gem has a few issues that I would like to fix.  I cloned the git repo and installed the gem locally, hoping I could mess with the source code.  When I edit the source code nothing happens, so now I am thinking that I must rebuild the gem every time I make a change.

My question is this:
Should I be able to edit the source code of the gem and see results immediately, or should I use the source code as a plugin to my rails app, and then rebuild the gem only when I have made significant progress?

Thank you,

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mess with the source code of the *installed* gem to change the behavior of what you have installed.  But unless you are playing path games this won't affect the gem itself even if you rebuild.

What I generally do is this:

- Set up a development area where I can make changes & test them (e.g. run unit tests, spec, etc.)
- Do most of my work there
- When I've got something I like, rebuild the gem and try a test install
- If that works to my satisfaction, push it.

Also, if you are using git hub they should automatically rebuild the gem for you every time you push a commit with an updated gemspec (e.g., you've changed the version number).

Comment: My problem is that I am having trouble setting up the dev area.  I have the git repo cloned in its own dir.  Now I need to have a file where I run tests on the plugin code.  If I try to put require 'blackbook' at the top of the test file, I get an error because the gem is not installed.

Comment: If the file is only used locally for testing, put a more detailed path in the require.  E.g. "require '../lib/blackbook'" or whatever.  Also, consider using one of the testing frameworks, which can make your life a lot easier.

Comment: i think my question was just too general to get the specific response that i want.  you definitely gave some great hints so i am going to close this question...but i just wanted to know which testing framework do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I use this rake task to make keeping my gem up to date while working on it. It uses a version number stored in a file at the root named 'VERSION'

```
desc "Build and install homer gem"
task :update do
  version = File.open('VERSION') { |f| f.read }.to_s
    `gem build homer.gemspec`
    `gem install ./homer-#{version}.gem`
end
```

and in the gem spec:

```
s.version = File.open('VERSION') { |f| f.read }.to_s
```